# CSS mesh perspective/transform

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Is it possible to do free transforms of an element using CSS - similar to a mesh transform?

[image]

The closest I can get to this is using something like `transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(45deg);` with three elements, but I would like it to be one continuous `img` element.

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible. CSS does not have anything like that effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mesh+transform

Answer (score 2):

You can consider 3 elements and `background-image`. The trick is to adjust the background-size/background-position to create the illusion of one continuous image.

Hover to see the result:

```css
.box {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;;
  background-size: 300% auto;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: 300% auto;
  transform: perspective(800px);
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

.box:before {
  right: 100%;
  background-position: left;
  transform-origin: right;
}

.box:after {
  left: 100%;
  background-position: right;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.box:hover::before {
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(50deg);
  filter: brightness(0.8);
}

.box:hover::after {
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(-50deg);
  filter: brightness(0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800)">
</div>
```